# css vw meaning when used with font-size

Tags: html, css

My understanding is that the "vw" units in CSS refer to 1% increments of the viewport width.

However, when I create a mono-spaced font that is supposed to be 10% of the viewport width, [it winds up closer to ~6% (1/16)](https://jsfiddle.net/yn2rk5jd/):

```
<div style="width: 100%; background: green; color: white; font-size: 10vw; font-family: monospace;">
123456789012345670
</div>
```

If I use a font that is not monospace it not quite as bad, but it is still off:

```
<div style="width: 100%; background: green; color: white; font-size: 10vw; font-family: serif;" id="test8">
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
</div>
```

I am using "M" as this is the typical "widest character" in any font.  In [this case](https://jsfiddle.net/yn2rk5jd/1/) I see 11 characters, so each one is about 9% of the viewport width.  This is still off by 10%.

So what gives?  What does "vw" actually mean when used with font size, especially when each character has the same width?

Comment: Look at the font file. It's possible that letters are not as big as in other font you used for the same pixel size. It's common "issue" that different fonts need different px sizes to look the like they were the same size.

Comment: are you taking into account the `letter-spacing` between characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying the font-size describes the size of the em-square. The font metrics include the advance width of each glyph which is proportional to the em-square. It is the total of the advance widths (and letter and word spacing) that determines how many characters fit on a line.

For example, if we take the monospaced Windows Courier New font, the glyphs all have the same advance width which is 1229/2048 of the font-size.

So, if we have a font-size of 10vw and 0 letter and word spacing, we should get 100 / (10 x 1229/2048) = 16.66 characters (or 16 characters once truncated) in a line box that's as wide as the viewport.

```css
body {
margin:0;
font-size:10vw;
font-family:'Courier New';
word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```